# CherryPy MVC and Jinja2, Remove Trailing Slash

Tags: python, html, model-view-controller, jinja2, cherrypy

If i have a form and type localhost/dash?formdata1=sdsaad it redirects to localhost/dash/?formdata1=sdsaad. I need it to stay as localhost/dash?formdata1=sdsaad so i can use the form data for stuff.

I am using CherryPy 4 and Jinja2.

I am using this as my MVC: https://simpletutorials.com/c/1702/MVC+with+CherryPy+and+Jinja2

This is the relative data in the controller for the Dash link.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, *kwargs):
    fail = self.parsetest(kwargs) #Points to my Model. The model just does a try and except and returns fail on except.
    return self.render_template({'Fail': fail})
```

This is the Mount point in Base.py

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(DashController(), '/dash', site_config_path)
```

The config has no data on Dash at the moment

Comment: Bump, sorry if im not meant too.